# Selector not up to date in component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, redux-selector

I have a simple app using react-native and redux:

```
import { createReducer, createActions } from 'reduxsauce';
import Immutable from 'seamless-immutable';

/* ------------- Types and Action Creators ------------- */

const { Types, Creators } = createActions({
  setAnswer: ['answer'],
});

export const QuestionnaireTypes = Types;
export default Creators;

/* ------------- Initial State ------------- */

export const INITIAL_STATE = Immutable({
answers: [],
});

/* ------------- Selectors ------------- */

export const QuestionnaireSelectors = {
getCurrentAnswers: (state: any) => state.answers,
};

/* ------------- Reducers ------------- */

const setAnswer = (state, { answer }) => {
  return ({
    ...state,
    answers: [...state.answers, answer],
  })
};

/* ------------- Hookup Reducers To Types ------------- */

export const reducer = createReducer(INITIAL_STATE, {
  [Types.SET_ANSWER]: setAnswer,
});
```

then in my component I simply do

```
const handleSubmitPress = (data) => {
  setAnswer({ question_id: currentQuestion.id, value: data.questionInput });
  console.log(getCurrentAnswers)
};
```

but every time this handler runs the log shows the previous state (an array containing all the already added but not the one added just in the previous line)

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately
The set state is not synchronous. You will have the updated state on the next re-render. If you put the console.log outside of the handleSubmitPress, you will see that it is being called with the updated state on the next render

Comment: thank, that solved the issue